# After upgrade to 18.04 / gnome: how can I activate keyboard shortcuts for maximizing windows with <Alt><Space><x>?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04, I miss the keyboard shortcut to maximize / unmaximize a window.

In 16.04, I pressed `<Alt><Space>`, and the following menu opened:

[image]

Afterwards I pressed `x` to maximize or unmaximize the referring windows. Every menu entry had a certain key assigned.

Thes key assignments seem to be gone in 18.04.

How can I activate it again?